# Gitignore not working for nested files

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a repo with the following directory structure:

```
src/
    main/
        resources/
            application-local.properties
            application-local-db.properties
        java/
            <lots of source files here>
.gitignore
```

And a gitignore that looks like:

```
/.project
/target/
/bin/
/.settings/
/.classpath
/generated/
.idea
*.iml
```

I would now like to add `src/main/resources/application-local.*` to my gitignore so changes to this file don't get committed/pushed. So I changed my gitignore to:

```
/.project
/target/
/bin/
/.settings/
/.classpath
/generated/
.idea
*.iml
/application-local-memcached.properties
/application-local.properties
```

I then made some changes to `application-local.properties` and when I do a `git add . -n` I see git getting ready to stage that change! **Why isn't git honoring my gitignore changes to ignore changes to `application-local.*`?**

Comment: Because the file you want excluded is not located in the root folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming `application-local.properties` was already checked-in to the repo. If yes, you'll have to remove it (or make a copy of it in the interim), commit the deletion of the file, rename the copy you created to the original filename and post that `.gitignore` will start ignoring changes to that file.

Alternately, `src/main/resources/` would technically be empty from Git's standpoint given that you want Git to ignore those property files. Git doesn't allow one to add empty directories to the repo, but if you still want to keep this directory structure, create a dummy file `src/main/resources/.gitkeep` so that you can actually commit and maintain that directory path in the repo.